# Unwanted white space in IEEE latex template

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, ieeetran

I am writing a paper, in which I don't know the reason for this white spacing shown below:

[image: Spacing problem between equations and new lines]

[image: Spacing problem between section, figures and newlines]

This appears between sections, equations, and figures. However, this is the given template from IEEE. Could anyone help me?

PS: I am using `pdflatex` in windows. The only customization I did in the template is using the `psfrag` package, for substitution in `.eps` figures. Also, I could not provide a `MWE` because, I am not sure how to insert a whole class into `MWE`.

Comment: [Welcome!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/34551) Without looking at the relevant portion of your code, it's impossible to tell. Please provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/34551) (you can edit your first message to add some code).

Comment: you have hardly given any information but I would guess that you are using a class with `\flushbottom` and there is a large unbreakable box on the next page, but it is hard to guess if you show no code

Comment: @Clément and David I shall try to put a MWE to this.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, when I used the `\raggedbottom` the problem indeed vanishes. So, yes as you said then it is indeed a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: although you presumably have some sub-optimal markup on the next page which is preventing the page shown from having more text. `\raggedbottom` just puts the white space at the bottom, it would be better not to have the space.